# Issue in setting partition size in Dask dataframe while reading from DB

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to read from table and set the size of each chunk to 256MB without specifying divisions and partition. But when I checking the size of each partition it is less than 60 MB

Minimal complete code for stimulating issue:

Generate Data:

```
import string
import sqlite3

from itertools import permutations
def create_table(cur):    
    query = '''create table sample(id int, name text)'''
    cur.execute(query)
c = 1
def get_chunk(n, chunk_size):
    chunk = []
    global c
    for d in permutations(string.ascii_uppercase, n):
        t = c , ''.join(d)
        chunk.append(t)
        c += 1
        if len(chunk) >= chunk_size:
            yield chunk
            chunk = []
    return chunk

def insert_data(cursor, n, chunk_size): 
    for chunk in get_chunk(n, chunk_size):
        cur.executemany('insert into sample values (?, ?)', chunk)
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
create_table(cur)
conn.commit()
insert_data(cur, 6, 1000)
conn.commit()
```

For processing

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_sql_table('sample', 'sqlite:////path/to/test.db', 'id', bytes_per_chunk=268435456)
def fun(df):
    print(df.name.count())
    print(df.info())
df.map_partitions(fun).compute()
```

Answer (score 1):

`dd.read_sql_table` guesses how to make divisions based on just the first `head_rows` rows (five by default), in the case that you don't provide further information. There are many ways in which this estimate can be wrong! In this case you seem to be out by a decent factor, and maybe you can investigate the specific reasons why this might be, but in general, you may be better off providing some of more specific information (number of partitions or explicit start/stop limits) if you want more control.